# How to select all list elemnets of a specific <ul> in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html-lists

```
//first ul    
<ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    //second ul
        <ul >
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
```

I want to write some text only into all the `<li>` elements of 2nd unordered list. I want my jquery to ignore `<li>`s in first `<ul>`

Here is what I attempted, but it did not work:

```
$("ul:nth-child(1) li").eq(1).each(function(){
                $(this).text("Lorem Ipsum");

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I want to write some text only into all the `<li>` elements of 2nd unordered list.*

You can use [**:eq(index)**](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

> Select the element at index n within the matched set.

Note: Zero-based index of the element to match

Use

```
$("ul:eq(1) li").text("Lorem Ipsum")
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrgEL/)

EDIT: Be wise to chooses between `:eq()` and `:nth-child()`

See comparative example

[**Demo with :eq()**](http://jsfiddle.net/9XQWE/) vs [**Demo with :nth-child()**](http://jsfiddle.net/QdfFa/)

Comment: @Mitchel, Read [docs](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2) jQuery iterates for you. You don't need `.each()`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('ul:nth-child(2) li').each(function(){
    $(this).text("Lorem");
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/aY5mu/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `:eq()` selector,

```
$("ul:eq(1) > li").each(function(){
   $(this).text("Lorem Ipsum");
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrgEL/1/)

Comment: @OP you are changing your questing most often.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("ul:eq(1)").find("li").each(function(){
  $(this).text("Lorem Ipsum");
});
```

:eq(1) selects the element with index 1. Then you can use `.find()` to get the child elements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select nth-child(2) not 1 and not eq(1) since you need all list:

```
$("ul:nth-child(2) li").each(function(){
     $(this).text("Lorem Ipsum");
});
```

---

As difference notified by @Rajaprabhu you may wish to use eq() method instead of nth-child():

```
$("ul:eq(1) li").each(function(){
    $(this).text("Lorem Ipsum");
});
```

Comment: +1 yep I read jquery API. It is not 0 based index like other functions

Comment: nth-child will not be a best choice, if html contains many ul inside many other elements, then this selector will select all the matched child ul.. right..?

Comment: if there are more even it selects only nth-child(2) like eq(1), any doubt??

Comment: C-link see the example, @RajaprabhuAravindasamy is correct,  see comparative examples http://jsfiddle.net/9XQWE/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/QdfFa/

Comment: @C-link no doubts, it will select the nth-child(2) and make a collection if possible, but :eq(1) wont behave like that.. it will select exactly one element from the element collection.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to find out all the 'ul" of page then use below code

```
$j("ul").each(function () {

});
```

if you want to find out specific "ul" under specific class or element then use below code

```
$j(".ClassName ul").each(function () {

});


$j("#ParentElementId ul").each(function () {

});
```

Comment: I am not using any IDs or classes. Only the element itself. BTW what is this $j. I really have no idea about it

Comment: Hi, I am using mentioned code ( $j = jQuery.noConflict();) to avoid jQuery conflict you can directly call this method like Jquery("ul").each...

Answer (score 0):

you could give a Id to your second ul and selected directly

```
$('#anyId li').each(function(){
    $(this).text("Lorem Ipsum");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$("ul:eq(X) li").text("Text to write in second ul")
```

Where X = what UL you want. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2gj6/2/